# Is there a MySQL client that can run multiple queries in one tab?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

Note that I'm not asking about how to send multiple SQL statements in one request to the DB server.

I've worked with [SQL Server Management Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio) for a while. And I liked how you can have a lot of SELECT statements in one .sql file. And if you pressed F5, it will run your SELECT statements independently and multiple result sets will be presented to you. Is there something like this for MySQL?

With all of the MySQL clients I've tried. One tab is limited to 1 SQL statement. You can write multiple statements, but you can only run only one of them at a time.

I tried SQuirel, HeidiSQL, MySQL Workbench CE, dbeaver. Right now I'm stuck with the free version of SQLYog. Each all have great features. But not one has this feature I was looking for.

Edit:
Thanks to Aishatter for suggesting **Toad for MySQL**. I made a screenshot of it showing the feature I was looking for:

[imgur screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cuj3Q.png)

It can even remember previous executions, this is the "Set 6" and "Set 7" as seen in the screenshot.

Edit2:
Toad was too slow for me. And so I ended up with SquirrelSQL which also has this feature I'm looking for, but note that I think this is only present in their latest snapshot build - 20150623_2101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [Toad for MySQL](http://software.dell.com/products/toad-for-mysql/)?

It is works a charm. Like a MySQL on a SQL Management Studio.

You can execute multiple queries at the same time. With a feature of query formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Here you go HEIDI MYSQL

http://www.heidisql.com/download.php

This is one of the finest tools I have been playing  with since last 4 years.